# SIGSEGV error on gcc (Ideone, codechef) works fine on pc

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

This is the code for a problem on codechef.

```
#include<stdio.h>

inline int chkIsDiv(int n1, char* ptr)
{
    int i=0, b=0;
    while(ptr[i] != '\0')    
    {
       b=b*10+(ptr[i]-48);
       b%=n1;
       i++;
    }     
    if(b==0)
       return 1;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
  int t, a, b=0, i;
  char c[252];

  scanf("%d",&t);
  while(t>0)
  {
    scanf("%d",&a);
    i=0;
    getchar();
    while((c[i++]=getchar()) !='\n');
    c[i-1]='\0';
    if(a!=0 && chkIsDiv(a,c)) printf("%d",a);
    else if(a==0) {
      i=0;
      while(c[i] !='\0') printf("%d",c[i++]-48);
    }
    else
    {
      for(i=a-1; i>=1; i--)
      {
         if(a%i==0) {
            if(chkIsDiv(i,c)) {
                printf("%d",i); 
                break;
            }          
         }         
      }         
    }
    printf("\n");
    t--;          
  }

  //getch();
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I run the above code on ideone, it compiles the code successfully, but when I put input test cases, it gives segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) Runtime Error.
My submission link on ideone: http://ideone.com/qGclvK

Similarly, on codechef when I submit my problem it gives same error.(I guess since both uses the same compiler from SPOJ).

But when I run the same code on my machine it works fine with every input condition specified in the problem and also for corner cases. The code is running fine in both windows and linux. And also I believe the algorithm I used is correct.

I used Dev-C++ default compiler in windows and gcc in linux.

I know the error is occurring due to some invalid memory reference, but i'm not able to find where the problem is, which statement is causing problem, as it is running fine on my system.

Can anyone help me with this, I'm kind of beginner??

[SOLVED] #thank_to_MayankJain.
Got it solved. The problem was that I was assuming a '\n' at the end of every line, but in this case the last line will not contain any '\n' so I tested for EOF marker now, and works fine.

Here's the modified code http://ideone.com/qGclvK

Comment: Why are you using getchar() and all. The whole problem involve integers only. Can you explain me the logic of getting a line and then breaking up into integers ?

Comment: The problem invovles handling numbers of order 10^250. So I'm scanning all the digits in array using getchar(). If you want to look problem statement here's the link http://www.codechef.com/problems/GCD2

Comment: Do you know what line it's failing on?

Comment: If the number can have 250 digits, you need to declare `char c[251]` to allow room for the `\n`.

Comment: @Barmar No it's only saying runtime error(SIGSEGV)

Comment: @Barmar I declared the array char c[252], infact I also tried c[300] but result is same.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia - As SPOJ inputs TC's via a file the last line won't contain a new line character. Please try creating a file and taking input from that file and don't give new line character in last line.

Comment: @MayankJain OK, solved now thanx. I was so dumb, didn't thought about it. The inputs are given from file and the last line will not contain any '\n'. Therefore I checked for EOF marker in last case.

Comment: It seems kinda odd that SPOJ doesn't include a newline after the last line...it means it isn't formally a text file that they're giving you as input, as a text file without a newline at the end isn't formally a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

@MayankJain OK, solved now thanx. I was so dumb, didn't thought about it. The inputs are given from file and the last line will not contain any '\n'. Therefore I checked for EOF marker in last case. –  abhishekkannojia